# Footer Positioning: footer not appearing at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to position my footer at the very bottom of every page, but am having trouble doing so. The footer gets positioned perfectly at the bottom for pages with long content, but it gets placed abruptly in the middle of pages with little content. I have attached a sample image to let you see that it is not getting placed at the bottom for some pages. My html and css for the footer is below. I tried using `position: fixed;` but that had the unwanted affect of making the footer visible at all times; I only want it at the very bottom of every page. How can I achieve that?

**application.html.erb**

```
<body>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <%= render :partial => 'layouts/header' %>
        <div id="flash_messages">
            <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
            <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg && !msg.empty? %>
            <%- end -%>
        </div>
        <%= content_tag(:div, "&nbsp;", :class => "clear") unless flash.empty? %>
        <%= yield %>
        <footer>
            <%= render :partial => 'layouts/footer' %>
        </footer>   
    </div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
#footer {
    position: static;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dddfe1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
.clearfix {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work either. The footer stays in the middle for pages with little content.

Comment: That fixes the problem for small content pages, but for large pages, which need to be scrolled down to get to the footer are now not looking fine. What happens with position: absolute; is that the footer gets placed at the bottom of the "visible" page; when you scroll down, the footer stays there, covering the page's content! It is not at the very bottom anymore for long pages.

Comment: @msc don't forget to add `position: relative;` to the parent! http://jsfiddle.net/ofkscfdr/

Comment: Okay, so I did get it partially working. The footer however is now covering essential sidebar content.

Comment: This is not acceptable since it hides a lot of helpful feautures on my website i.e. the footer simply covers elements beneath it.

Comment: @GINCHER do you know clearfix class is usually reserved for clearing floats? Also you don't need to set parent element as relative, just give your footer position absolute and it'll work :)

Comment: @Mandeep If you won't add the `position: relative;`, the footer will be standing in the end of the screen, not in the end of the website.

Comment: @GINCHER oh yeah my bad i thought `msc` wanted to set it on the screen end. Yep you'll need position: relative for it

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is actually this:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dddfe1;
}
```

side note: you will face inherent difficulty with getting a multi-browser solution to a footer (particularly if you plan to support mobile devices), so researching this topic may prove quite fruitful.

also, this is not a javascript or jquery question, not to be too picky, but please only add tags that are relevant to the actual implementation.

Comment: Not to be too picky, but if you read my question, I've stated that I do not want the effect that position: fixed; brings along.

Comment: i'm sorry that should have been position: absolute; edit: you will actually need what GINCHER has provided below, if you don't have that, by the by. the position: relative; sets up a different coordinate system for position: absolute; to operate on

Comment: That doesn't fix the original problem either. The footer stays in the middle of the page for pages with little content and does not go down to the bottom for some reason. It also further places the footer in the middle for large, scrollable pages.